# A non foreign key cannot be referenced in a path expression

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a before update trigger/class to automatically create a new opportunity when handover is set to accepted. I am receiving a compile error "A non foreign key cannot be referenced in a path expression" and I know this is because the related fields e.g. "h.Account__c.region__c "are not available in the trigger.New context. What would be the most efficient way to query the account fields and then apply the same logic that I have written in the class?

```
public with sharing class HandoverToOpportunity {

        public static void generateHandoverOpportunity(List<Handover__c> acceptedHandover) {
            Map<Id, Opportunity> HandoverOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

            for(Handover__c h: acceptedHandover){
                if((h.Handover_Status__c == 'Accepted') && (h.Account__c.region__c == 'EMEA')){
                HandoverOpps.put(h.id, new Opportunity( OwnerId              = h.Assigned_Rep__c,
                                                        accountId            = h.Account__c,    
                                                        Related_Contact__c   = h.Contact__c,
                                                        Converting_Event__c  = h.Converting_Event__c,
                                                        Converting_Rep__c    = h.Converting_Rep__c,
                                                        Converting_Source__c = h.Converting_Source__c,
                                                        Type                 = h.Type__c,
                                                        Amount               = 40000,
                                                        CloseDate            = date.today() + 270,
                                                        Name                 = h.Type__c + ' For '+ h.Account__c.Name,
                                                        stageName            = 'Discover Need'
                                                        ));   
                } else if ((h.Handover_Status__c == 'Accepted') && (h.Account__c.region__c == 'AMER')){
                HandoverOpps.put(h.id, new Opportunity( OwnerId              = h.Assigned_Rep__c,
                                                        accountId            = h.Account__c,    
                                                        Related_Contact__c   = h.Contact__c,
                                                        Converting_Event__c  = h.Converting_Event__c,
                                                        Converting_Rep__c    = h.Converting_Rep__c,
                                                        Converting_Source__c = h.Converting_Source__c,
                                                        Type                 = h.Type__c,
                                                        Amount               = 500000,
                                                        CloseDate            = date.today() + 180,
                                                        Name                 = h.Type__c + ' For '+ h.Account__c.Name,
                                                        stageName            = 'Discover Need'
                                                        ));      
                }
            }
            insert HandoverOpps.values();
            for(Handover__c ho: acceptedHandover){
                if(HandoverOpps.containsKey(ho.id)){
                    ho.opportunity__c = HandoverOpps.get(ho.id).id;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are a number of questions on SFSE about how to access related-record fields in a trigger. What have you found by searching? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I found some similar questions about getting the related record fields but was struggling with creating the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a set of related account ids, and then query for a map of accounts like this:

```
Set<String> accountsIds = new Set<String>();
for(Handover__c h : acceptedHandover) {
    accountIds.add(h.Account__c);
}
Map<String, Account> accounts = [
    SELECT Name, region__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN :accountIds
];
```

And then simply get an account from the map, like `accounts.get(h.Account__c).region__c == 'EMEA'`

EDIT:

To avoid situation where Account would be null, you might want to assign it to a variable, and then check it.

```
Account handoverAccount = accounts.get(h.Account__c);
if(... && handoverAccount != null && handoverAccount.region__c == 'EMEA') {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please note this code will fail if `h.Account__c` is null, because `accounts.get(...)` returns null and you immediately dereference it.

Comment: This can be easily avoided by simply asigning the value to a variable, and then checking if it's not null

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to reference a parent record, or reach through a lookup to get fields from the parent record, is to use the `__r` suffix for custom fields, or to drop the `Id` part of the name for standard fields.

**Incorrect**

```
h.Account__c.Name
```

**Correct**

```
h.Account__r.Name
```